# Systemd bind rules have no effect in user slice

Tags: systemd, cgroups

I want to prevent the user `test` (1000) from binding to any ports other than say 1537 so according to [systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#SocketBindAllow=bind-rule) I configure `SocketBindAllow=1537` and `SocketBindDeny=any` for the user Slice.

But I can still log in as user test, run `nc -l 1234` and bind to port 1234. I have verified that this nc process is part of the user slice. Can I use the `SocketBind*` options to limit the ports a user can can bind to and how?

```shellsession
# systemd --version
systemd 252 (252.6-1)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT -GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY +P11KIT +QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -BPF_FRAMEWORK -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified
# cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/socket.conf
[Slice]
SocketBindAllow=80
SocketBindAllow=1537
SocketBindDeny=any
EOF
# systemd-daemon-reload
# systemctl show user-1000.slice | rg Bind
SocketBindAllow=1537
SocketBindAllow=80
SocketBindDeny=any
DropInPaths=/usr/lib/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/10-defaults.conf /etc/systemd/system.control/user-1000.slice.d/50-SocketBindDeny.conf /etc/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/socket.conf
```

I also tried to allow port 80 to test whether this only works for privileged ports but as expected, to 80 the `test` user cannot bind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

It works just as described but `systemd` has to be compiled with `+BPF_FRAMEWORK` which is currently not the case on Debian, therefore the options have no effect.